# Some characters are not displayed properly in Android webview

Tags: android, encoding, webview

I used the "loadDataWithBaseURL" with "utf-8".

But some characters are not showing like:

[image]

The encoding error is irregular.

Whenever I try to build, I get an error, and sometimes it comes from a different letter.

Here is the Html source code.
The result was the same, with or without a custom font.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="th">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-16LE" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <link href="css/manual.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'noto';
            src: url('file:///Android_asset/font/notosansthai-regular.ttf');
        }
        body {
            font-family: 'noto';
            font-style: normal;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ol>
            <li>เปิดเครื่องวัดความอิ่มตัวของออกซิเจนในเลือดด้วยการกดปุ่ม เปิด/ปิด</li>
            <li>หนีบแคลมป์ให้กางออก และวางนิ้วลงไปในช่องของแคลมป์ของเครื่องวัดความอิ่มตัวของออกซิเจน</li>
            <li>หลังจากเครื่องวัดสัญญาณชีพได้แล้ว ค่าความอิ่มตัวออกซิเจนในเลือด อัตรกาารเต้นของหัวใจ จะแสดงขึ้นที่หน้าจอ</li>
            <li>ค่าการวัดจะแสดงค่าใหม่เสมอ กดปุ่ม [ส่งค่า] </li>
            <li>เมื่อการวัดเสร็จสมบูรณ์ ให้นำนิ้วออกจากแคลมป์</li>
        </ol>
        <div class="text-center">
            <img src="img/img_td8255.png" width="80%;">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I think the error is on your "I get an error" (on building). Try to solve that problem first. if you have an encoding error on source files, do not expect you can find the errors on output. Maybe you used an editor with wrong encoding, and copy-paste text with a different encoding (without editor realizing it). BTW are you sure about `UTF-16LE`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I've tried other tools like Notepad, Visual Studio Code, but I've seen the same results.
I tried using it instead of UTF-8 but it was the same result.